# Why is the radius of my circle too large (Unity using Line Renderer)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, line, renderer

I am trying to draw a circle in Unity using Line Renderer but I'm having a few problems.

1. A circle is being drawn but its radius is larger than it should be. (the yellow sphere is the radius it should be and the black circle is what is being drawn)
   Example: When trying to draw a circle with a radius of 10.0f, the circle drawn will have a radius of something larger than 10.0f.
2. The circle doesn't fully connect. There are a couple points in the circle where something went wrong. (these areas are circled in the picture)

[image: screenshot of my Unity editor]

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public static class GameObjectEx
{
    public static void DrawCircle(this GameObject container, float radius, float lineWidth)
    {
        var segments = 360;

        LineRenderer line = container.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        line.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default"));
        line.startColor = Color.black;
        line.endColor = Color.black;

        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        line.startWidth = lineWidth;
        line.endWidth = lineWidth;
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;

        var pointCount = segments + 1;
        var points = new Vector3[pointCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++)
        {
            var rad = Mathf.Deg2Rad * i;
            points[i] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(rad) * radius, 0f, Mathf.Cos(rad) * radius);
        }

        line.SetPositions(points);
    }
}
```

I've tried following a few different tutorials for drawing a circle with Line Renderer and the code I posted is the closest I've gotten to something that works. I'm pretty sure problem #1 is being caused by "var rad" but I haven't been able to figure it out. For problem #2, I've tried increasing the value of segments but the two broken parts are still present and unchanged.

Comment: Because the scale isnt 1?

Comment: @BugFinder the scale of the player gameobject doesn't impact it